# Regular expression Python Django url

Tags: python, regex, django

When I try runserver, there is an error at this regular expression:

```
url(r'^articles/get/(?<article_id>)\d+/$', views.article)
```

Can you please explain - where I was wrong?

Comment: `^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$` - The `P` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You must be looking for

```
^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
                ^            ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU3aR9/1)

The first issue is that you failed to use a named capture group correctly, and the second issue is that you did not capture anything by setting the closing `)` right after the group name, while you want to capture 1+ digits with the `\d+` into the `article_id` group.

Also, some reference on the named groups can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `(?P<name>...)`
>   Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring matched by the group is accessible via the symbolic group name name.

Comment: Yes, for testing Python regex, regex101.com is good, but there are still bugs. For the current expression, it will work as shown. Make sure you actually test the pattern in the real environment if you are using more sophisticated patterns.